# Rails: is it bad practice if I do Dynamic routing through controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, rails-authorization

Here is what I do and I feel like it's not a good idea and it's anti-pattern:

Authenticated users get directed to Home Controller and in controller depending on user status I directed them to different routes.
Is it bad if I do this:

```
if user.status == "accepted"
   redirect_to ### some view
else
  redirect_to ### another view
end
```

I thought about using `CanCan`, but I think it might be overkill

Comment: Its in a before_action?

Comment: Uh, no directly to that, well that is pretty much I have in the action.

Comment: Ok I'd say why not, but I dont really understand the need :) what is bad practice is to check model's internals outside of it, you should have an `accepted?` method

Comment: @apneadiving I thought if I had few if & else statements for the logic it might be a make the controller sluggish.

Comment: I dont think so, but if the reason is to catch non accepted users and prevent them from accessing multiple sections in your app, move it to a before_action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends** on a case. It could be acceptable. I can't give advice as that would be expressing an opinion, however, I can give you an alternative since you are clearly interested in how to do this differently.

When working with [Sorcery authentication](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) gem (and as far as I know, [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) offers the same approach) one applies a filter to a controller, that redirects any non-logged-in user to a page you specify (it's sensible to redirect to login page).

This is implemented using a `before_filter` (same as `before_action`, really). Methods fed into it are built up into a chain that is called on every controller's action (unless parameters state otherwise). If any of the filter methods `redirect`s or `render`s, chain execution is halted. This can be seen in the server's logs.

*This approach works really well if you need to apply that **same condition and redirect** to **multiple actions**. If it's not the case and it's the only place where you do this check, your current implementation may be just enough.*